# Elegant solution to write to a database as well as a rfid card in a somewhat atomic way

Tags: sql-server, database, atomic, smartcard, rfid

Assuming you want to write some data to a RFID card and some data to a database.
Theoretically the connection to the database might break at any time and the connection between the card and the card reader might break at any time too.
Your goal is to design it in a kinda atomic way that you either end up with both or none being written.

Is there any elegant approach to solve this?
Any hints are appreciated :)

(I'm using MS SQL Server and the Windows Smart Card Module (Winscard.dll) in case it makes any difference)

Comment: There's no such thing as "somewhat atomic". If you need two separate records either written or not together, you'll need a a transaction mechanism.

Comment: By "somewhat" i mean resembling an atomic operation as much as possible, reasonable and feasible even though it is probably not possible to be truly atomic. A distributed transaction sounds nice but its probably not worth the extra effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a record before you start your update of the RFID card, then update this record when complete.  In this way you'll also be able to spot half-completed updates, and act accordingly.

1. Insert a record into the database with a status of 'incomplete'. Give it a timestamp, a unique id, and any other pertinent information you require to uniquely describe the RFID write attempt
2. Write to RFID card
3. Update the record inserted in step 1. with a 'completed' or 'failure' status

Then have a process which resolves incomplete records after a timeout period has elapsed (either by trying again, or whatever else you want to do).

Do not try to hold open a database transaction while you communicate with your RFID card, as this will:

1. Give you unwanted (and potentially lengthy) locks on your database
2. Rollback upon failure, which will remove any evidence you tried to do something to your RFID card

Answer (score 2):

Define 'somewhat'. True atomic way require the smartcard module to participate in a distributed transaction and I'm not aware of any smartcard API and/or provider supporting transaction.

Anything less atomic means not atomic and you can play games of retry and status until the cows come home, but unless the smartcard write is [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) you have zero chance of correctness in the presence of failures. If the smartcard write is idempotent then is simply a matter of retry and ack logic: write to DB with status 'pending', commit, then write to smartcard, then write to DB with status 'Done'. On crash you need a process to scan for status 'Pending' and retry. Since the smartcard write is idempotent, the retry is safe. And yes, [Using Tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) is relevant here.

Comment: Java Card and many other Smart Card OS do support transactions. But I think you are referring to it *participating* in the DB transaction, and that's a different kind of fish.

Comment: If they support transactions, they should be able to enroll in a distributed transaction too. Basically, if they either implement [Open XA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA) or a driver can be written to bridge the card supported transaction with XA suport.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to update the database first, and then predicate the RFID update on the success of the database update. The database update should be wrapped in a transaction to make it atomic as well.

Of course you'll want to roll back the database update if the subsequent RFID update fails. Therefore I would consider including a transaction audit with the database update. If the RFID update fails, you can then return to a consistent state by invoking a rollback routine for your DB update.

Hope this helps!